# How to make long words hyphenated in R markdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, hyphenation

How can I make long words hyphenated in R markdown?
My problem is that, some words in my documentaion are too long, and as long as some of these words are located at the end each line, these words go out of borders of each page.

[image]

Here is an exampple: as seen in this picture "DNAbin2genind:" is out of border. How can I make this word hyphenated so in the Pdf format it will look like

> ... DNAbin2-
>   genind: ...

?

Comment: Since LaTeX is used for producing the PDF, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182597/140850 might be helpful.

Comment: DNA... looks to be in tt font. How to hyphenate a word in tt font would depend on how you input it. Please show the relevant code